# How to place admob not on top of screen(in java class for marmalade sdk)

Tags: java, android, admob, marmalade

I have class:

```
class AdmobAds
{
   private static final int ADVIEW_NOT_INITIALIZED = 1;
   private AdView adView;

   public int InitAds(final String pub_id)
   {
    LoaderActivity.m_Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {

adView = new AdView(LoaderActivity.m_Activity, AdSize.BANNER, pub_id);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
LoaderActivity.m_Activity.addContentView(adView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
});
       return 0;
   }
   public int ShowAds()
   {
if(adView!=null){
LoaderActivity.m_Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}});
} else { 
return ADVIEW_NOT_INITIALIZED; 
}

       return 0;
   }
   public int HideAds()
   {
if(adView!=null){
LoaderActivity.m_Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}});
} else { 
return ADVIEW_NOT_INITIALIZED; 
}
       return 0;
   }
}
```

And i need to place AdMob banner in the identified locations ix and iy. 
When I try to add Layout, in which we put a banner application falls.

Application write on Marmalade SDK, so do not have access to the XML, a little experience does not allow me to deal with the problem itself.

Comment: What a mess! Please reformat your code, respect others' eyes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I used for displaying the ads at the top:-

```
adView = new AdView(LoaderActivity.m_Activity,AdSize.BANNER, appKeyFinal);      
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(LoaderActivity.m_Activity);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parentParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adNinjaLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adNinjaLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
LoaderActivity.m_Activity.addContentView(layout,parentParams);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I hope this can help.